# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I faced with a problem, was google it for a half of this day. Nothing could help me. It was working. But after that something has happened and i didn't capture that.

Here are TomCat Catalina Log

```
31-Jan-2016 00:35:27.278 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] null.null HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
31-Jan-2016 00:35:27.282 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] null.null HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update}
31-Jan-2016 00:35:27.283 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] null.null HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
31-Jan-2016 00:35:27.376 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] null.null HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
31-Jan-2016 00:35:28.170 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] <unknown>.<unknown> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
31-Jan-2016 00:35:29.632 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] null.null HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
31-Jan-2016 00:35:30.331 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
31-Jan-2016 00:35:30.349 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
**31-Jan-2016 00:35:30.377 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.**
31-Jan-2016 00:35:32.709 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/manager
31-Jan-2016 00:35:32.907 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/manager has finished in 197 ms
```

---

Localhost Log

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:563)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/2146013565.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

My DatabaseConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("cards.server.repository")   
@EnableTransactionManagement    
@ComponentScan(value = "cards.server")
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:database.properties",
        "classpath:hibernate.properties"}
)
public class DatabaseConfig extends IOException {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("db.entity.package"));
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
        ds.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.initialSize")));
        ds.setMinIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minIdle")));
        ds.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.maxIdle")));
        ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis")));
        ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis")));
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.testOnBorrow")));
        ds.setValidationQuery(env.getRequiredProperty("db.validationQuery"));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return manager;
    }

    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.getProperty(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.getProperty(env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.getProperty(env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cards.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>cards.server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- cmd + alt + v -->
    <properties>
        <spring-core.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-core.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.38</mysql-connector-java.version>
        <commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
        <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <spring-webmvc.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-webmvc.version>
        <spring-test.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-test.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-webmvc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>jstl</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.2</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>${jta.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>postgresql</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${postgresql.version}</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-test.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Hoping for your help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError means - **incompatible versions** in pom.xml

Fix. pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <spring-core.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-core.version>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.34</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
    <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
    <!--<postgresql.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresql.version>-->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <spring-webmvc.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-webmvc.version>
    <spring-test.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-test.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also suffered from this problem.
But,When I  changed version of spring and  JDK Version then this problem was solved.
So,it may to work out for you