# Spring java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Thanks for having a look at this. I have created a Java web app using Spring and Maven in Eclipse. However when attempting to launch the Tomcat server I receive the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$FieldCallback;)V
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:418)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:931)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From doing a bit of research it looks like it might be a dependency conflict, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108637/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-util-reflectionutils-clearcache). I have run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and received the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ web ---
[INFO] com.starling.streamliner:web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.starling.streamliner:service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.starling.streamliner:domain:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.0)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.3.0.Final)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.39:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.39:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.39:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.39:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-debugger:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |        \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for cycle)
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.harbororubber.enquiry:web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.harbororubber.enquiry:service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.harbororubber.enquiry:domain:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (com.starling.streamliner:domain:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.starling.streamliner:service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.0.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-extras:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.0.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-extras:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet-wildcard:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.6)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-mustache:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.6)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 12.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-autotag-core-runtime:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-jsp:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.6)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-freemarker:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-freemarker:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.6)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-velocity:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-velocity:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-el:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-mvel:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-ognl:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-compat:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.0.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.0.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] \- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.010 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-05T14:45:32+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/354M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out and cannot find a conflict related to Spring. Any help in spotting a conflict or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! I haven't posted the pom.xml files since the dependency tree should cover that, it's also split over the project files. If I can post anything else of use then please let me know.

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:` = dependencies version conflict, there is a maven plugin called "Enforcer" (I let you searching) which can help you finding the conflicts.

Comment: Can you post the entire POM? fairly strange as the spring errors all look good - is there anything down as a provided scope that might be pulling different versions at runtime?

Comment: Thanks for those, I'll have a look at enforcer. The web app consists of 6 projects meaning 6 poms, however trying to include just one of these in my post went beyond the character limit! Is there a better way to include them on here? The only items with a provided scope are: `<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html#doWithLocalFields-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback-), the method `doWithLocalFields` was added to `spring-core` from version 4.2 onward. You are showing that you are including the version 4.3.9 which should have this method. But obviously, you end up using an old version (< 4.2) of `spring-core` somehow. You need to investigate your deployment structure and find out how it is getting included. You need to get rid of that old version and replace it with a newer one.

Comment: Thanks for this @VHS, I went into my local Maven respoitory and deleted old versions of `spring-core` then ran Maven 'Update Project'. Within the `spring-core` location within the Maven repo a folder called '3.2.0.RELEASE' appeared. So something is bringing this in and I guess that is causing the conflict. Any idea how to trace where this could be coming from when `dependency:tree` isn't picking it up? Thanks

Comment: @SamB To find out where the classes come from (and possible duplicates), I use this script inside Git Bash : `for i in lib/*.jar; do if unzip -l $i| grep ReflectionUtils; then echo $i; fi ; done`. In this case to find out `ReflectionUtils` classes inside the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, I have managed to fix the problem. However, I have no idea why this should work as the fix but in the end I added a Maven exclusion to the spring-orm dependency. Below is the dependency entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Post your entire POM in your question. We just don't know which dependencies and versions you are pulling. What is the value of spring.version?

Comment: I did try to post the POM but it exceeded the character limit so I hoped the dependency tree would cover it. The value for spring.version is 4.3.9.RELEASE. Thanks for you help in solving this @VHS

Answer (score 0):

This error mainly caused due to spring version mismatched, You can first revert back to older version of your code and try to update version one by one.

Answer (score -1):

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError means incompatible versions in pom.xml*

scroll down and check if any of your spring dependency is conflicting with an older version. I suspect  spring-web:jar dependency. Better explicitly define all the spring dependency in our pom and use the same version.